# Why mongodb upsert counter doesn't reflect actual changes?

Tags: mongodb

Consider following query

```
var collectionName = "test";
db.createCollection(collectionName);
db.getCollection(collectionName).insert({
  "_id" : 1, "char" : "Gandalf", "class" : "barbarian", "lvl" : 20
});

db.getCollection(collectionName).bulkWrite([
    { 
      insertOne: {
        "document": {
            "_id" : 2, "char" : "Dithras", "class" : "barbarian", "lvl" : 4
        }
      }
    },
    { 
      updateOne: { 
        filter: { "_id": 1}, 
        update: { $set: {"class" : "mage"} }, 
        upsert: true 
      } 
    }
])
```

Which results in:

```
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "deletedCount" : 0.0,
    "insertedCount" : 1.0,
    "matchedCount" : 1.0,
    "upsertedCount" : 0.0,
    "insertedIds" : {
        "0" : 2.0
    },
    "upsertedIds" : {}
}
```

my question is why updating of a document with `id:1` doesn't get into `upsertedIds`? Isn't this document just being updated with upsert? Or am I missing anything?

According to the documentation it only adds information to `upsert` if it doesn't find any document (so it's actually more like `inserted`), but this case I don't know which items got updated.

Is it possible to get which documents got modified when executing a query?

---

To avoid XY problem: I want to see bulk operation items taht failed (e.g. when trying to update non-existing document with `upsert:false`) and log IDs that triggered the failures.

Comment: It's in matchedCount.

Comment: It's just a regular count whilst I need document ids

Comment: But update never returned document ids. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#returns

Comment: @AlexBlex it seems that it's not doable with mongo... Sad to hear that.

Comment: Not the way you want. See my answer if I get your XY edit right.

Comment: @AlexBlex thanks for an answer, however I meant something different. I'd like to have all ids which get processed, i.e. either upserted or just updated. Since we can't get any information about updated rows then it's impossible to achieve the result.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't follow. You have upserted ids when documents were added with upsert : true, the rest were "just updated".

Comment: @AlexBlex look. I sent several entries which could insert or update. Some operations could fail. I'd like to know which exact operations failed. For example I sent 10 documents with ids 1-10, but operations on documents with id 3,4, and 7 failed for some reason (e,g, I was updating without upsert and there was no documents with such ids). I'd like to have these ids back to report `Documents with ids 3,4, 7 were not updated with batch operation`.

Comment: Frankly, it makes even less sense to me =) Do you do upsert or not? What is "failed"? A write operation can fail, e.g. insert of a document with duplicated unique key, the driver will return error with details of the failed operation. Update operation that doesn't match any documents is not a failure but absolutely valid usecase. You get ids of inserted and upserted documents in the response. You can get ids of missing documents by running the aggregation from my answer. Попробуй может по-русски объяснить  or update the question with better example and the results you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `Update operation that doesn't match any documents is not a failure but absolutely valid usecase. ` - right, I buy it. Okay, what's about internal mongodb errors? I believe if something very bad occured during some operations it won't rise any errors but will just silently write whatever he can, as per documentation which desribes `ordered:false` behavior.

Comment: yes, unordered bulk will do whatever it can but not silently. It's quite vocal about errors: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/BulkWriteResult/#BulkWriteResult.writeErrors. Try it yourself - make 2 inserts with same _id.

Comment: Cool. I hope it gets mapped by my db driver.

Comment: Hope driven development? =)

Answer (score 0):

You can collect document ids when you prepare your bulk update, then check which of them don't exist after the update. E.g. for document ids 1, 2, and 3 that you updated with `upsert:false`

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: null }},    
    { $project: { _id: [ 1, 2, 3 ] }},
    { $unwind: "$_id" },
    { $lookup: {
       from: "test",
       localField: "_id",
       foreignField: "_id",
       as: "exists"
    }},
    { $match: { exists: { $size:0 }}},
    { $project: { exists:0 }}
])
```

will return id's of filters that didn't match any document, i.e. "failed" in your terminology.